# Regularly Updated JSON Overwrite vs Parse

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a frontend Application in Javascript with jQuery

I get a JSON Object every few seconds.
I have to incorporate this JSON Object into my local data.

I can either take the Object and completely replace a local Object with it, or I could check each entry and only replace the changed entries.

In case it makes a difference:

- I don't know the structure of the object in advance
- The object maximum depth is usually 2 ({ "a": { "b":"c"}})

Which one is faster in terms of processing time?
 
Is there even a straight answer or does it depend on the object and / or browser?

Comment: It depends entirely on the object and its structure, and how much data it contains. It sounds like you may be better off looking at using websockets to push changes to data to the client instead of syncing up a resource which you poll every X seconds.

Comment: Do you have any links that could help me understand the specific mechanics involved? Unfortunatly, I can't change the way I receive the data at this point.